# List of land cover classes in particular area and use them as an item for ui.Select

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to identify the list of land cover classes in particular area and use them as an item for ui.Select. And I would like to use below given label for identified land cover values. I have drafted a code, but I am facing with an error.  Is anyone can help me to improve it?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/74284d0174febea1be10a4dd9dccffc6?as_external

Error:

[image]

```
    var block = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[10.884499359130846, 50.55773169053401],
              [10.884499359130846, 49.37053314015084],
              [13.433327484130846, 49.37053314015084],
              [13.433327484130846, 50.55773169053401]]]);

    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
      .select('LC_Type1')
      .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-05-01');

    var landcover = dataset.first();
    var block_landcover = landcover.clip(block);

    var Vis = { min: 1.0, max: 17.0,
      palette: [
        '05450a', '086a10', '54a708', '78d203', '009900', 'c6b044', 'dcd159',
        'dade48', 'fbff13', 'b6ff05', '27ff87', 'c24f44', 'a5a5a5', 'ff6d4c',
        '69fff8', 'f9ffa4', '1c0dff']};

    Map.addLayer(block_landcover, Vis, 'Land cover');

    print(block_landcover);

    var block_landcover_vec = block_landcover.reduceToVectors({
      geometry: block,
      crs: landcover.first().projection(),
      geometryType: 'polygon'
    }); 
    print(block_landcover_vec);

    Map.addLayer(block_landcover_vec);

    var land_cover_types = ee.List(block_landcover_vec.aggregate_array('value'));

    var land_cover_select = ui.Select({
                  items: land_cover_types,
                  placeholder: 'Select a Mask',
                  onChange: function(value) {
                    var land_cover_value = value;
                    },
                  style: {width: '200px'}
                  });  

print(land_cover_select);

    [{label: 'Evergreen Needleleaf Forests', value: '1'}, 
    {label: 'Evergreen Broadleaf Forests:', value: '2'},
    {label: 'Deciduous Needleleaf Forests', value: '3'}, 
    {label: 'Deciduous Broadleaf Forests', value: '4'},
    {label: 'Mixed Forests', value: '5'}, 
    {label: 'Closed Shrublands', value: '6'},
    {label: 'Open Shrublands', value: '7'}, 
    {label: 'Woody Savannas', value: '8'},
    {label: 'Savannas', value: '9'}, 
    {label: 'Grasslands', value: '10'},
    {label: 'Permanent Wetlands', value: '11'}, 
    {label: 'Croplands', value: '12'},
    {label: 'Urban and Built-up Lands', value: '13'}, 
    {label: 'Cropland/Natural Vegetation Mosaics', value: '14'},
    {label: 'Permanent Snow and Ice', value: '15'}, 
    {label: 'Barren', value: '16'},
    {label: 'Water Bodies', value: '17'}]
```

Comment: Based in your comment about a way for directly determining areas from raster file, instead of converting it to vector and making a list, I posted an answer. I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based in your comment about a way for directly determining areas from raster file, instead of converting it to vector and making a list, I developed following code for determining area (in hectares), for all classes of MODIS landcover, in your **block_landcover** image. Code link is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3838646d01e62b629d9fa9eba324643f).

```
var block = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[10.884499359130846, 50.55773169053401],
          [10.884499359130846, 49.37053314015084],
          [13.433327484130846, 49.37053314015084],
          [13.433327484130846, 50.55773169053401]]], null, false);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
  .select('LC_Type1')
  .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-05-01');

var landcover = dataset.first();
var block_landcover = landcover.clip(block);
var scale = block_landcover.projection().nominalScale();

print ("MODIS Scale", scale);


var Vis = { min: 1.0, max: 17.0,
  palette: [
    '05450a', '086a10', '54a708', '78d203', '009900', 'c6b044', 'dcd159',
    'dade48', 'fbff13', 'b6ff05', '27ff87', 'c24f44', 'a5a5a5', 'ff6d4c',
    '69fff8', 'f9ffa4', '1c0dff']};

Map.centerObject(block_landcover, 8);
Map.addLayer(block_landcover, Vis, 'Land cover');

var classes_list = ['Evergreen Needleleaf Forests', 'Evergreen Broadleaf Forests', 
  'Deciduous Needleleaf Forests', 'Deciduous Broadleaf Forests', 
  'Mixed Forests', 'Closed Shrublands', 'Open Shrublands', 'Woody Savannas',
  'Savannas', 'Grasslands', 'Permanent Wetlands', 'Croplands', 'Urban and Built-up Lands', 
  'Cropland, Natural Vegetation, Mosaic', 'Permanent Snow and Ice', 'Barren', 'Water Bodies'];

var list = ee.List.sequence(1, 17, 1);

var areas = list.map(function(l){

    var iter = ee.Number(l).int();

    var areas_list = ee.List([]);

    var areas = block_landcover
     .eq(iter)
     .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000))
     .reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
        geometry: block,  // a geometry
        scale: 463.3127165275,   // scale for MODIS
        maxPixels: 1e9  
    });

    areas_list = areas_list.add(areas.values()).get(0);

    return areas_list;

}).flatten();

var fus_list2 = ee.List(classes_list).zip(areas);

print(fus_list2);
```

After running the script, it can be observed in Console Tab printed areas for all classes in **block_landcover** image visualized in Map View of GEE.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I would like to use the classes that are not equal to 0 in ui.Select. I have tried to do it, but it did not work. Could you please help to improve the code. https://code.earthengine.google.com/d234776f084fc5f748939fc57b5c3163

Answer (score 1):

Your specific error you are asking for: you tried to get the 'first` image of an image. It is an function which only works on collections (you already got the first image in var landcover).

```
var block_landcover_vec = block_landcover.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: block,
  crs: landcover.projection(), // remove .first()
  geometryType: 'polygon'
});
```

There are more errors popping up then. Use a client-side list for ui.Select items and define a function correctly for the onChange argument.

Comment: I have improved the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/25d5e64b627dacf9561b87a4b601f4ac?as_external. Anyway I could not get what I want. I was wondering is there a way to list available land cover classes in particular area directly from raster file instead of converting it to vector and making a list?