# List for ui.Select from Modis land cover classes in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Previously, I have asked a question and received very valuable answers and useful solutions. But, still I could not get what I want. I really need support to solve the issue. I am still struggling on making a list of land cover classes in particular study area for `ui.Select`?

My question was: "I would like to identify the list of land cover classes in particular area and use them as an item for ui.Select. And I would like to use below given label for identified land cover values. I have drafted a code, but I am facing with an error. Is anyone can help me to improve it?"

Link for the question: [List of land cover classes in particular area and use them as an item for ui.Select](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355348/list-of-land-cover-classes-in-particular-area-and-use-them-as-an-item-for-ui-sel)

```
var block = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[10.884499359130846, 50.55773169053401],
          [10.884499359130846, 49.37053314015084],
          [13.433327484130846, 49.37053314015084],
          [13.433327484130846, 50.55773169053401]]]);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')
  .select('LC_Type1')
  .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-05-01');

var landcover = dataset.first();
var block_landcover = landcover.clip(block);
var scale = block_landcover.projection().nominalScale();

print ("MODIS Scale", scale);


var Vis = { min: 1.0, max: 17.0,
  palette: [
    '05450a', '086a10', '54a708', '78d203', '009900', 'c6b044', 'dcd159',
    'dade48', 'fbff13', 'b6ff05', '27ff87', 'c24f44', 'a5a5a5', 'ff6d4c',
    '69fff8', 'f9ffa4', '1c0dff']};

Map.centerObject(block_landcover, 8);
Map.addLayer(block_landcover, Vis, 'Land cover');

var classes_list = ['Evergreen Needleleaf Forests', 'Evergreen Broadleaf Forests', 
  'Deciduous Needleleaf Forests', 'Deciduous Broadleaf Forests', 
  'Mixed Forests', 'Closed Shrublands', 'Open Shrublands', 'Woody Savannas',
  'Savannas', 'Grasslands', 'Permanent Wetlands', 'Croplands', 'Urban and Built-up Lands', 
  'Cropland, Natural Vegetation, Mosaic', 'Permanent Snow and Ice', 'Barren', 'Water Bodies'];

var list = ee.List.sequence(1, 17, 1);

var areas = list.map(function(l){

    var iter = ee.Number(l).int();

    var areas_list = ee.List([]);

    var areas = block_landcover
     .eq(iter)
     .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(10000))
     .reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
        geometry: block,  // a geometry
        scale: 463.3127165275,   // scale for MODIS
        maxPixels: 1e9  
    });

    areas_list = areas_list.add(areas.values()).get(0);

    return areas_list;

}).flatten();

var fus_list2 = ee.List(classes_list).zip(areas);

print(fus_list2);
```

Link for the solution: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3d42306c59c4c3df5794e1001a51f305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this what you are searching for? See comments in the code for the additions I made to your previous answer.

```
// make a dictionary of region names and index of the area
var dictSimple = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(classes_list, 
                                         ee.List.sequence(0, classes_list.length-1));

// map of the dictionry, get the area and return the area when > 0
var dict = dictSimple.map(function(key, val){
  var newVal = areas.get(val);
  return ee.Algorithms.If(newVal, newVal)
});
print('example dictionary',dict)

var land_cover_select = ui.Select({
    // get the landcover names (not zero) on the client-side
              items: dict.keys().getInfo(), 
              placeholder: 'Select a Mask',
    // define function to return the area when a region is selected
              onChange: function(key) {
                print(dict.get(key))
                },
              style: {width: '200px'}
              });  

print(land_cover_select);
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/266f8327a857c7c085818c085a4444f4)